# NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my react website I login i want to generate a token. I'm calling my API and respone is undefined.

```
  [object Error]{config: Object {...}, description: "Network Error", 
  message: "Network Error", name: "Error", request: XMLHttpRequest {...}, response: undefined, stack: "Error: Netw..."}
```

This is my react code.

```
 const axios = require("axios");
const fakeAuth = {

isAuthenticated: false,
authenticate(cb: any) {
this.isAuthenticated = true;
axios.post('https://localhost:44310/api/Users/Token' )
.then((response : any) => {
console.log(response)
})
.catch((error : any) =>{
console.log(error)
})
},
signout(cb: any) {
this.isAuthenticated = false;
},
getValue() {
return this.isAuthenticated;
}
};

export default fakeAuth;
```

and this my API token method.

```
private string Token()
{

    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("qwertyuiopqwertyuiop"));
    var signInCred = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);
    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: "localhost",
        audience: "localhost",
        expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1),
        signingCredentials: signInCred
        );
    var tokenString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    return tokenString;
}
```

Comment: your method should be public it's private due to which can't be found

Comment: Now I' getting this error.
NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier). 
[object Error]{config: Object {...}, description: "Request fai...", message: "Request fai...", name: "Error", request: XMLHttpRequest {...}, response: Object {...}, stack: "Error: Requ..."}

Comment: And this error too.
HTTP401: DENIED - The requested resource requires user authentication.
(XHR)GET - https://localhost:44310/api/Users

Comment: check your controller and action. if you already made the method public, it is related to routing section API.. see the routing configuration and edit it to understand API or you can simply use [RoutePrefix("api/Users/Token")] data annotation